# How to program a Byzantine node?

Tags: simulation, consensus, traffic-simulation, adversarial-machines, byzantine

I have a network simulator, and I need to program a Byzantine node class for that simulator. The purpose of these Byzantine nodes is to test the resiliency of an arbitrary networking protocol.

Implementing random behaviour would be easy, but not very damaging to the network. The same goes for simply going offline.

Most papers I've read outline some worst-case scenario. Is there some way to automatically deduce, given the network topology, latency, and other characteristics of the network, a decent strategy for the Byzantine nodes to use?

It could be probabilistic, so I considered using adversarial AI, but I am afraid of performance issues during training of those adversaries.

Is there a logically deductive solution? If not, what is the closest probabilistic solution?